# What AppIntent Parameter type to use for a Note?

Tags: ios, swift, appintents

I'm trying to receive a list of Notes from Apple Notes as a shortcut parameter. Some testing shows that I can receive them as `String` or `IntentFile` (RTF format), like so:

```
struct NoteIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Use Note"
    static let description: LocalizedStringResource = "Use a Note."

    @Parameter(
        title: "Note",
        description: "Apple Notes item"
    )
    var note: [IntentFile]
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Use \(\.$note)")
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result(value: note.first?.fileURL?.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

But the `IntentFile` type does not carry the usual metadata on each Note like summary, folder, tags, creation date and last modified date. I can only infer note the title from the file name. Is there a more appropriate parameter type that would allow me to receive the Note contents along with its metadata?